# r calling variables from list

Tags: r, list, function, input

I was hoping to find some help with a current issue. I've written a function (`F1`), which takes as input the name of another function (`F2`) and some other input. The input for `F2` might differ, what I'm trying to do, is to use a list as input to `F1` which than will use the list as input for `F2`.

```
F1<-function(input.list,F2){out=F2(input.list)}
```

However, I would like to avoid having to extract all variables in `input.list` using something like `a=input.list[[1]]`, I do not want to name all possible input variables for all possible `F2` in `F1`, rather I would like to have the variable names in `input.list` to be used directly as input for `F2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do, but below are two examples that could point you in the right direction. The wrapper functions here supply arguments to `FUN`(in your case `F2`) but also take their own arguments (`unique_F1_factor`).
Firstly, if you want to work with lists of arguments supplied to your wrapper `F1`, then I suggest using `do.call` in the body of the function, like this:

```
# If you want to work with lists ----
F1_list = function(input_list,unique_F1_factor,FUN) {
  out = do.call(FUN, input_list)
  # Do stuff in F1, e.g.:
  out=unique_F1_factor*out
  return(out)
}
```

Alternatively, you could just avoid a list altogether:

```
# Wrapper function ----
F1 = function(...,unique_F1_factor,FUN) {
  out=FUN(...)
  # Do stuff in F1, e.g.:
  out=unique_F1_factor*out
  return(out)
}
```

*Note that if using a random number generator such as `rnorm`, the results will differ for `do.call(rnorm, args)` and `rnorm(args)` even if you specify `set.seed`.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

Just to clarify how you would supply arguments in each case. For `F1_list` you would do:

```
# Example with list:
F1_list(
  list(sd=1,mean=3,n=10),
  unique_F1_factor = 10, 
  FUN = rnorm
)
```

If instead you want to avoid the list, do:

```
# Example w/o list ----
F1(
  sd=1,
  mean=3,
  n=10,
  unique_F1_factor = 10, 
  FUN = rnorm
)
```